# If $x \equiv 2 \pmod 3$, show that $x=\pm x_1 x_2 \cdots x_t$, where $x_i\equiv 2 \pmod 3$

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, modular-arithmetic, eisenstein-integers

This question comes from *A Classical Introduction to Modern NT* (Ireland & Rosen), chapter $9$ $\#17$. Note that $D$ is the set of Eisenstein integers.

> **Exercise 9.17** An element $x \in D$ is called primary if $x \equiv 2 \pmod 3$. If $x$ and $y$ are primary. show that $-xy$ is primary. If $x$ is primary, show that $x=\pm x_1 x_2 \cdots x_t$, where the $x_i$ are (not necessarily distinct) primary primes.

The first part is simple to prove:
If $x \equiv y \equiv 2 \pmod 3$, then $-xy \equiv -2 \cdot 2 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$, which is primary.

How does the 2nd part of my proof look?

If $t\geqslant 3$ is odd, then we write $x_i \equiv 2 \pmod 3$
\begin{align*}
            x &= x_1 x_2 \cdots x_t\\
            &= (2\cdot 2) \cdots (2\cdot 2) \cdot 2\\
            &\equiv 1 \cdots 1 \cdot 2 \pmod 3\\
            &\equiv 2 \pmod 3.
        \end{align*}
If $t\geqslant 2$ is even, then we write $x_i \equiv 2 \pmod 3$
\begin{align*}
            x &= x_1 x_2 \cdots x_t\\
            &= (2\cdot 2) \cdots (2\cdot 2)\\
            &\equiv 1 \cdots 1 \pmod 3\\
            &\equiv 1 \equiv -2 \pmod 3.
        \end{align*}
Therefore, $x =\pm x_1 x_2 \cdots x_t$.

Is my proof correct? Am I allowed to assume the end and work backwards? I think that is more or less what I have done.

Comment: Yes. Certainly the second part can be proven used by 1st one.

Comment: I believe that going with induction should work. Building on the first part, $\gamma \rho \delta \equiv 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$, and so on for $-16, 32, -64$.

Comment: Note in the second part, the multiplicands are resticted to be primes, so it takes more than induction on the first part. Effectively you need to show that all *primary* Eisenstein integers are products of *primary* Eisenstein primes.

Comment: Modulo $3$, you should probably think of $2$ as $-1$. Then you’re just considering a product in which all factors are $-1$.

Comment: Is your proof correct? No. Likely that you missed the whole point.  In $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_3]$ if $\omega\not \in \sqrt{-3}\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_3]$ then there is $k$ such that $\zeta_3^k \omega-2\in 3\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_3]$.

Comment: @reuns Could you post a solution that details the correct proof? It seems many other users said my proof was correct.